# Cannot save to internal storage Android Studio

Tags: android, file, android-studio, kotlin, save

It seems as though I've tried everything that people have been suggesting. YouTube videos, stackoverflow posts, but I just cannot seem to save a file using these methods. I run the save method with no error, but when I try to read it later it prompts me with no file found. Issue occurs on both emulator and real phone.

Code:

```
fun loadFile() {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        d(TAG, "doesn't exist")
        return
    }

    try {
        val scanner = Scanner(openFileInput("data.json"))
        d(TAG, scanner.nextLine())

        dateList = gson.fromJson(scanner.nextLine(), FileList::class.java).list

        scanner.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        if (e !is NoSuchElementException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_loading, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            d(TAG, "Error loading file", e)
        } else {
            d(TAG, "empty file")
        }
    }
}

fun saveFile() {
    val fileList = FileList(dateList)
    val json = gson.toJson(fileList)

    try {
        d(TAG, json)
        val output = openFileOutput("data.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        output.write(json.toByteArray())
        d(TAG, "wrote")

        output.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_saving, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        d(TAG, "Error saving file", e)
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
01-27 17:26:29.828 5918-5918/me.elian.contactsaver D/ContactSaver: doesn't exist
01-27 17:26:36.616 5918-5918/me.elian.contactsaver D/ContactSaver: {"list":[{"year":2018,"month":1,"day":27}]}
01-27 17:26:36.617 5918-5918/me.elian.contactsaver D/ContactSaver: wrote
01-27 17:26:38.190 5918-5918/me.elian.contactsaver D/ContactSaver: {"list":[{"year":2018,"month":1,"day":27},{"year":2018,"month":1,"day":26}]}
01-27 17:26:38.190 5918-5918/me.elian.contactsaver D/ContactSaver: wrote
01-27 17:26:48.972 5955-5955/me.elian.contactsaver D/ContactSaver: doesn't exist
```

Comment: `d(TAG, "doesn't exist")`. Bad message! What does not exist? Do you know? Change to `d(TAG, "doesn't exist: " + file.getAbsolutePath());`. Moreover you did not show us how you set up `file`. Tell uscthe path please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by *"it prompts me with no file found"* you mean the *"doesn't exist"* information from Logger.
From what I checked your `saveFile()` method is working correctly and the file gets created.
This `!file.exists()` at the beginning `loadFile()` returns true, because internal files are managed differently and thus the file doesn't exist (it has different path than *"data.json"*) and your method finishes due to `return` statement.

So remove

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    d(TAG, "doesn't exist")
    return
}
```

block and it should work correctly.